Unknown Exception type for crash detail on Google play console. My exception type seems to be reduced to an obfuscated abbreviation
Before I used to get a meaningful known Exception type for the crash details for my app on Google Play Console. But for some time now I don't see what the exception type is. Only the rest of the stacktrace which makes it much harder to debug because I don't what exception I am trying to resolve in the first place. Please what could have made my exception types to suddenly start being obfuscated and abbreviated. Thank you.
Exception ha.i:
  at com.africaningenuity.financialcontributions.view_model.MainActVm.getInsideGroupRepository (MainActVm.kt:27)
  at com.africaningenuity.financialcontributions.fragment.MemberContributionsFrag$memberContributionsVm$2.invoke (MemberContributionsFrag.java:61)
  at com.africaningenuity.financialcontributions.fragment.MemberContributionsFrag$memberContributionsVm$2.invoke (MemberContributionsFrag.java:60)
  at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue (ViewModelLazy.kt:47)
  at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue (ViewModelLazy.kt:35)
  at com.africaningenuity.financialcontributions.fragment.MemberContributionsFrag.getMemberContributionsVm (MemberContributionsFrag.kt:60)
  at com.africaningenuity.financialcontributions.fragment.MemberContributionsFrag.setUpViewModel (MemberContributionsFrag.kt:170) 
  ...

